# How to export stored password from seahorse

Tags: seahorse

Is there any way to export stored secrets from seahorse 3.8.2 (running on Ubuntu 13.10) (not public keys) in order to import them (directly or after a transformation) into a keepass2 database? I researched for some time now without a result (neither positive nor negative).

Comment: I added a feature request on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1317249

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answering to the Amias' request, due to Apacar's response...**

In **Seahorse** interface, **Passwords** tab, click the right button on your **Keychain** folder (named `<name>`), click **Change Password**, enter your **Old Password** in the first field and leave the other fields empty and click **OK** button, then click the **Use Unsafe Storage** button. After that, the `<name>.keyring` file, in `~/.gnome2/keyrings` or `~/.local/share/keyrings`, will be decrypted.

Then, in order to keep your passwords more secure during transportation, you could make a compressed copy of the file (protected and encrypted by password, `<name>.keyring.{7z,rar}`) through the Compress option of the Nautilus context menu. And, after that, undo the password change of your Keychain.

Comment: I don't find a *Use Unsafe Storage* button.

Answer (score -1):

you can remove the keyring password and will find a decrypted version of the keyring in `~/.local/share/keyrings/<name>.keyring`

A simple Python script should be enough to convert the file to XML

Comment: please could you explain how these things are done