# Ubuntu 16.04 Encrypted USB Disk key not showing up in seahorse

Tags: encryption, seahorse, cryptsetup

I just noticed that I'm having a problem:
I have a external SSD with a encrypted partition on it.
At some point I must've accidentally enabled the "Remember forever" function for the password on my notebook which I didn't really want to do.
I tried to find the key in seahorse but I could only find the keys for my ssh backup and the backup encryption.

I've looked at other solutions to try to find the password but thanks to Bug [#1144703](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1144703) those keys apparently don't have attributes (which I can't confirm since I can't see the keys) so I couldn't really do anything using `secret-tool`

On my other computer it still works as it should; it gives me a password prompt.
Is there any way to remove just this specific key without needing to resort to just deleting the entire keyring?

---

System Info:

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Kernel: 4.17.9-041709-generic
cryptsetup 1.6.6
seahorse 3.18.0
```

---

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This may work for you https://askubuntu.com/questions/428001/how-to-export-stored-password-from-seahorse

Comment: I don't intend to make my keyring unsafe. This is not an option for me as it would compromise security. I only want seahorse to accurately show me my stored keys.

Comment: You could change it back.  It was an option that could solve your problem

Comment: Solved it by upgrading my system to 18.04. The problem doesn't exist here

Comment: The problem does indeed exist on (Xubuntu) 18.04. I was experiencing it just now. The solution was to "replace" (restart?) the Gnome keyring daemon: `gnome-keyring-daemon -r`. Now I'm being prompted for my external drive passphrase in Thunar, as desired.